# Can not read the content input in the dictionary file with python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I tried to make a python dictionary, the input of file format (.txt or .csv) and I want to match based database that I have.

This my file input

> John 
>   Smith
>   Ana
>   Adam
>   Steven

This My script

```
data = [{"name":"John","school":"A","age":"17"},
        {"name":"Smith","school":"B ","age":"16"},
        {"name":"Ana","school":"B","age":"19 "},
        {"name":"Adam","school":"C ","age":"18 "},
        {"name":"Steven","school":"B ","age":"19 "},]

file_input = open ('/home/ubuntu/data.txt', 'r')
for line in file_input:
    for get_name in data:
        if get_name ["name"] == line:
            print "Name :", get_name ['name'],
            print "School :", get_name ['school'],
            print "Age :", get_name ['age']
        else
            print ("No found name")
```

after I run the results

```
python myscript.py
No found name
```

Comment: `if get_school["name"] == line:` where is this `get_school` coming from?

Comment: @harshil9968 Was just about to answer that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change get_name to get_school

```
data = [{"name":"John","school":"A","age":"17"},
        {"name":"Smith","school":"B ","age":"16"},
        {"name":"Ana","school":"B","age":"19 "},
        {"name":"Adam","school":"C ","age":"18 "},
        {"name":"Steven","school":"B ","age":"19 "},]

file_input = open ('/home/ubuntu/data.txt', 'r')
for line in file_input:
    for get_school in data:
        if get_school["name"] == line.replace('\n','')::
            print "Name :", get_school['name'],
            print "School :", get_school['school'],
            print "Age :", get_school['age']
        else:
            print ("No found name")
```

Comment: thanks @harshil9968 ,I'm sorry there was a mistake in my script , but I 've tried like the answer you the same result

Comment: also when comparing use `line.replace('\n','')`

Comment: Instead of replacing just one kind of line ending character, a call to `rstrip()` would be more robust.  Also instead of a linear search in a list, it would be more efficient to store `data` as a dictionary mapping the name value of each element to the element.